# Diagnose HD deficiencies on Linux without admin rights

Tags: linux, hard-drive, command-line

Tools like `dd` or `hdparm` allows giving useful statistics on hard drive behavior, but require having a root access to the machine.

Is there a common reliable way to diagnose HD problems for non-power users?

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosing HD problems is notoriously difficult.

You might find that you have access to the SMART data from the disks which is available to the OS from `/proc/ide/hda/smart_values` so you can check if you have rights to that. If so, you may find you also have access to them via a GUI. Smartmontools is the most common GUI but many system monitors show the basics such as temp.

However, SMART, as Google have demonstrated is not a good indicator of upcoming issues though it may tell you something is horribly wrong - excessive temperature and/or error counts for example.

If you are allowed to boot from a CD drive, you could use a Live CD to check out the SMART data. However, you would then also have the ability to run the best disk tool I know of. It isn't free and isn't cheap at around USD90 but it is capable of identifying upcoming issues before they cause failures and data loss and is even capable of fixing transient issues that would eventually cause data loss. It is [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com) and I can recommend it. Use it preventively from time to time and as a tool of last resort if the disk is failing and you need to recover data.